# Firebase Like / Dislike system

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I implement the system like in the firebase database for the event. Likes the counter is here `EventModel -> likesInfo -> likesNumber`. The problem is that the data diverges, for example, if two users quickly (0.5 seconds) do like/dislike (or vice versa), then it may be that after the test is complete, both users stopped at dislike and likesNumber will be 1 (wrong) sometimes the difference can be 4-6 values. At the very beginning, I implemented it into the application using `runTransactionBlock`, then I thought that I would count by the number of interested users in the event and used cloud functions for this, but the result was even worse than it was in the application. I've seen a few examples, including firebase examples, ([one](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/database/DatabaseExampleSwift/PostTableViewCell.swift) of them) but some of them do not fit in that it will be necessary to store a large amount of data in the event model if the event has a lot of likes. Others I used, but there is no positive result. I enclose the code below. Please tell me how best to implement this system?

Code from app

```
  private func likeNumber(_ eventID: String, isLike: Bool, success: ((_ isCommited: Bool) -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let eventRef = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.events.rawValue).child(eventID).child(self.SubPath.likesInfo.rawValue).child(self.SubPath.likesNumber.rawValue)

            eventRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> TransactionResult in
                var likesNumber = currentData.value as? Int ?? 0
                debugPrint("likesNumber", likesNumber)
                if isLike {
                    likesNumber += 1
                } else {
                    likesNumber -= 1
                }

                if likesNumber < 0 {
                    likesNumber = 0
                }

                debugPrint("sumarry likesNumber", likesNumber)

                currentData.value = likesNumber

                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }, andCompletionBlock: { (error, commited, snap) in
                if let _error = error {
                    debugPrint("_error", _error.localizedDescription)
                    fail?(_error)
                    return
                }

                if commited {
                    debugPrint("commited", commited)
                }
                success?(commited)
                debugPrint("snap", snap?.value ?? "")
            })
        }
    }
```

Cloud functions

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var eventManager = require('../Managers/event-manager');

module.exports = functions.database.ref('eventLikedUsers/{eventID}/{userID}').onDelete(event => {
    const eventID = event.params.eventID;

    return eventManager.incrementLikesNumber(eventID, false);
});

module.exports = functions.database.ref('eventLikedUsers/{eventID}/{userID}').onCreate(event => {
    const eventID = event.params.eventID;

    return eventManager.incrementLikesNumber(eventID, true);
});
```

code from `EventManager`

```
exports.incrementLikesNumber = function incrementLikesNumber(eventID, isLike) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const eventRef = admin.database().ref()
            .child('events')
            .child(eventID)
            .child('likesInfo')
            .child('likesNumber');

        const prom = eventRef.transaction(currentData => {
            if (isLike) {
                return (currentData || 0) + 1;
            } else {
                return (currentData || 1) - 1;
            }
        });

        return prom
            .then(() => {
                return resolve('success operation')
            }).catch(error => {
                return reject(error)
            })
    });
};
```

Comment: I thought that it might as well be possible to make a queue of functions for one event by id and for example, until the first function is executed, do not start the second, but how is it better to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a queue in `EventsLikeManager` for like / dislike functions for one and event. If, for example, a function is performed for Event id 1 and a request is made to perform the same function for Event id 1, then the second request queues and waits for the first request to be executed. The code without refactoring but completely working, passed the tests.

```
class EventsLikeManager {

    // MARK: - Init

    private init() { }

    static let shared = EventsLikeManager()

    private let MainPath = EventsPaths.MainPath.self
    private let SubPath = EventsPaths.SubPath.self

    private let systemQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myapp.EventsLikeManager.systemQueue")

    // id, time,
    private var dict = [String : [EventSystemLikeDislikeModel]]()

    // MARK: - Like actions

    func likeEvents(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        guard newSystemEvent(event) else { return }
        _likeEvents(event, success: success, fail: fail)
    }

    private func _likeEvents(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        FirebasePerformanceManager.shared.likeDislikeAction(true)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if event.systemInfo.sourceIndex == EventSystemModel.Source.firebase.index {
                self.eventLikeInternalSourceAction(event, success: success, fail: fail)
            } else {
                self.eventLikeOutsourceAction(event, success: success, fail: fail)
            }
        }
    }

    private func eventLikeOutsourceAction(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true, completion: { (token, error) in
                guard token != nil else { return }

                let timestamp = Date().currentTimestamp

                event.systemTimeProperties.creationTimestamp = timestamp
                event.systemTimeProperties.updateTimestamp = timestamp
                event.systemInfo.sourceIndex = EventSystemModel.Source.firebase.index

                self.createEvent(event, success: {
                    self.userLikedEvent(event.id, notExists: {                        self.likeAction(event, timestamp: timestamp, success: success, fail: fail)
                    }, success: { (likeModel) in
                        // dislike
                        self.dislikeAction(event, success: success, fail: fail)
                    }, fail: fail)
                }, fail: { (error) in

                })
            })
        }
    }

    private func eventLikeInternalSourceAction(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        userLikedEvent(event.id, notExists: {
            self.likeAction(event, success: success, fail: fail)
        }, success: { (likeModel) in
            // dislike
            self.dislikeAction(event, success: success, fail: fail)
        }, fail: fail)
    }

    func createEvent(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            var commonError: Error?

            let eventRef = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.events.rawValue).child(event.id)

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            eventRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> TransactionResult in
                if (currentData.value as? [String : Any]) != nil {
                    debugPrint("TransactionResult.abort()")
                    return TransactionResult.abort()
                } else {
                    dispatchGroup.enter()
                    self.createEventLocation(event, success: {
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }, fail: { (error) in
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    })

                    currentData.value = event.toJSON()
                    return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
                }
            }, andCompletionBlock: { (error, isCommited, snap) in
                commonError = error
                debugPrint("isCommited", isCommited)
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .background), execute: {
                if let error = commonError {
                    fail?(error)
                } else {
                    success?()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private func createEventLocation(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let eventLocationRef = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.eventsLocations.rawValue)

            guard let geofire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: eventLocationRef) else { return }
            let coordinate = event.location.coordinate
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

            geofire.setLocation(location, forKey: event.id, withCompletionBlock: { (error) in
                if let _error = error {
                    fail?(_error)
                } else {
                    success?()
                }
            })
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - Likes' functions

extension EventsLikeManager {

    private func likeAction(_ event: EventModel, timestamp: Double? = nil, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            var finalTimestamp = Date().currentTimestamp

            if let _timestamp = timestamp {
                finalTimestamp = _timestamp
            }

            var commonError: Error?
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.likeNumber(event.id, isLike: true, success: { (isCommited) in
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }, fail: { (error) in
                commonError = error
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.addEventToUserList(event, timestamp: finalTimestamp, success: {
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }, fail: { (error) in
                commonError = error
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.addUserToEventUsersList(event.id, timestamp: finalTimestamp, success: {
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }, fail: { (error) in
                commonError = error
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                self.checkSystemEventQueue(event)
                if let error = commonError {
                    fail?(error)
                } else {
                    success?()
                }
                FirebasePerformanceManager.shared.likeDislikeAction(false)
            })
        }
    }

    private func likeNumber(_ eventID: String, isLike: Bool, success: ((_ isCommited: Bool) -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let eventRef = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.events.rawValue).child(eventID).child(self.SubPath.likesInfo.rawValue).child(self.SubPath.likesNumber.rawValue)

            eventRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> TransactionResult in
                var likesNumber = currentData.value as? Int ?? 0
                debugPrint("likesNumber", likesNumber)
                if isLike {
                    likesNumber += 1
                } else {
                    likesNumber -= 1
                }

                if likesNumber < 0 {
                    likesNumber = 0
                }

                debugPrint("sumarry likesNumber", likesNumber)

                currentData.value = likesNumber

                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }, andCompletionBlock: { (error, commited, snap) in
                if let _error = error {
                    debugPrint("_error", _error.localizedDescription)
                    fail?(_error)
                    return
                }

                if commited {
                    debugPrint("commited", commited)
                }
                success?(commited)
                debugPrint("snap", snap?.value ?? "")
            })
        }
    }

    private func addEventToUserList(_ event: EventModel, timestamp: Double, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let userID = RealmManager().getCurrentUser()?.id else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.userLikedEvents.rawValue).child(userID).child(event.id)
                let eventUserLike = EventUserLikeModel(eventID: event.id, systemInfo: event.systemInfo, dateInfo: event.dateProperties, systemTimestamp: timestamp)
                let json = eventUserLike.toJSON()

                ref.setValue(json, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if let _error = error {
                        fail?(_error)
                    } else {
                        success?()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    private func addUserToEventUsersList(_ eventID: String, timestamp: Double, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let userID = RealmManager().getCurrentUser()?.id else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.eventLikedUsers.rawValue).child(eventID).child(userID)
                let json = ["userID" : userID, "timestamp" : timestamp] as [String : Any]

                ref.setValue(json, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if let _error = error {
                        fail?(_error)
                    } else {
                        success?()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - Dislikes' functions

extension EventsLikeManager {

    private func dislikeAction(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            var commonError: Error?
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.likeNumber(event.id, isLike: false, success: { (isCommited) in
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }, fail: { (error) in
                commonError = error
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.removeEventFromUserList(event.id, success: {
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }, fail: { (error) in
                commonError = error
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.removeUserFromEventUsersList(event.id, success: {
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }, fail: { (error) in
                commonError = error
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                self.checkSystemEventQueue(event)
                if let error = commonError {
                    fail?(error)
                } else {
                    success?()
                }
                FirebasePerformanceManager.shared.likeDislikeAction(false)
            })
        }
    }

    private func removeEventFromUserList(_ eventID: String, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let currentUserID = RealmManager().getCurrentUser()?.id else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.userLikedEvents.rawValue).child(currentUserID).child(eventID)

                ref.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if let _error = error {
                        fail?(_error)
                    } else {
                        success?()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    private func removeUserFromEventUsersList(_ eventID: String, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let userID = RealmManager().getCurrentUser()?.id else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.eventLikedUsers.rawValue).child(eventID).child(userID)

                ref.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if let _error = error {
                        fail?(_error)
                    } else {
                        success?()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - Check events

extension EventsLikeManager {

    private func userLikedEvent(_ eventID: String, notExists: (() -> Void)?, success: ((_ userLike: EventUserLikeModel) -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let currentUserID = RealmManager().getCurrentUser()?.id else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let userLikedEventRef = Database.database().reference().child(self.MainPath.userLikedEvents.rawValue).child(currentUserID).child(eventID)
                userLikedEventRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                    guard snap.exists() else {
                        notExists?()
                        return
                    }
                    guard let json = snap.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
                    guard let likedEvent = Mapper<EventUserLikeModel>().map(JSON: json) else { return }
                    success?(likedEvent)
                }, withCancel: { (error) in
                    fail?(error)
                })
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - Like Actions Helpers

extension EventsLikeManager {

    private func getEventbriteAdditionalInfo(_ event: EventModel, success: (() -> Void)?, fail: ((_ error: Error) -> Void)?) {
        let eventbriteAPIManager = EventbriteAPIManager()
        eventbriteAPIManager.getAdditionalInfo(event, success: { (updatedEvent) in
            self.eventLikeOutsourceAction(updatedEvent, success: success, fail: fail)
        }, fail: fail)
    }

}

// MARK: - System

extension EventsLikeManager {

    private func newSystemEvent(_ event: EventModel) -> Bool {
        let timestamp = Date().currentTimestamp
        if dict[event.id] == nil {
            dict[event.id] = [EventSystemLikeDislikeModel(timestamp: timestamp)]
        } else if dict[event.id]?.count == 0 {
            dict[event.id] = [EventSystemLikeDislikeModel(timestamp: timestamp)]
        } else if var systemEvents = dict[event.id], systemEvents.count > 0 {
            debugPrint("systemEvents", systemEvents.count)
            let systemEvent = EventSystemLikeDislikeModel(timestamp: timestamp)
            systemEvents.append(systemEvent)
            dict[event.id] = systemEvents
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    private func checkSystemEventQueue(_ event: EventModel) {
        systemQueue.sync {
            guard var array = dict[event.id] else { return }
            guard array.first != nil else { return }
            array.removeFirst()

            debugPrint("checkSystemEventQueue array.count", array.count)
            if array.count > 0 {
                dict[event.id] = array
            } else {
                dict[event.id] = nil
                return
            }
            _likeEvents(event, success: nil, fail: nil)
        }
    }

}
```